# UWP как сделать отбрасывание тени для объектов?

Tags: c#, uwp

Надо сделать у кнопки отбрасывание тени. `DropShadowEffect` не доступен в `UWP`. Как быть? Неужели градиентом рисовать...

Answer (score 2):

**spriteVisual** (в code-behind) или  создать контейнер для твоего спрайтавизуала перед Button Подробнее можешь почитать тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41303196/how-to-create-a-drop-shadow-effect-for-the-button-in-uwp

Comment: А можно чу-чуть побольше информации по spriteVisual, а то в интернете только иноязычные мануалы...

Comment: @Denisok, пункт **Отбрасывание тени**:
https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/uwp/graphics/using-the-visual-layer-with-xaml

Answer (score 2):

Благодаря UWP Community Toolkit сделать это [проще простого](https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit/tree/dev/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.SampleApp/SamplePages/DropShadowPanel)

Comment: Разве такое отбрасывание тени не требует Anniversity Update?